# How can I index and query array with object in Dexie.js?

Tags: dexie

I would like ask if how can i search the supplier inside the array of objects ?
like this one, i want to search of suppliers inside the items

items: Array(4) 0: {
product_id: 487, product_name: "Control: Mosquitos Eucalyptus/ / 100ml", brand_id: "383", supplier_id: "204", supplier: "Control Freak", …}
1: {
product_id: 489, product_name: "Control: Mosquitos Lavender/ / 100ml", brand_id: "383", supplier_id: "204", supplier: "Control Freak", …
} 2: {
product_id: 491, product_name: "Control: Mosquitos Lemongrass/ / 100ml", brand_id: "383", supplier_id: "204", supplier: "Control Freak", …}
3: {
product_id: 491, product_name: "Control: Mosquitos Lemongrass/ / 100ml", brand_id: "383", supplier_id: "204", supplier: "Control Freak", …
}